# Проверка файла на существование

Tags: html, javascript

Как, имея код `<object data="file.htm"></object>`, определить, существует ли файл "file.htm"?

Мой сайт ucoz, если отсутствует этот файл, открывает "404.htm". Мне нужно, чтобы вместо "404.htm" в данном открывался, к примеру, файл "error.htm", который я создал сам. И мне необходимо, чтобы Javascript сначала проверял на существование "file.htm", а затем, если же его не существует, отображал в object мой файл "error.htm".

Answer (score 3):

js:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp .onreadystatechange = function() {  
    if (reqxmlhttp readyState == 4) { 
        if(xmlhttp .status != 200) { 
            window.location.href='/error.htm';
        }
    }
}
xmlhttp .open('GET', document.getElementById('file').getAttribute('data'), true);  
reqxmlhttp send(null);
```

html:

```
<object data="file.htm" id='file'></object>
```

Comment: не соглашусь, по моему проще так (в вашем примере я не вижу проверки на наличие файла )
var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp()
xmlhttp.open('GET', '/file.html', false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
  alert(window.open('/error.html'));
}

Comment: 200 статус означает, что файл существует.

Comment: @lampa да, вы правы:
 
    var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp() xmlhttp.open('GET', '/file.html', false); xmlhttp.send(null); if(xmlhttp.status != 200) { alert(window.open('/error.html')); }

Так как вам мой вариант?

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов всегда будет срабатывать. Да и вообще не будет работать, у вас ajax команда асинхронно работает.

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов т.е. полностью нерабочий.

Answer (score 1):

http://xmlhttprequest.ru/

Comment: http://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest
тут чуть подробнее